# jQuery Fading Text is Jumpy in IE8 and

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, fadeout

I'm having a problem fading in and out text with jQuery in IE8.
I'm using FlexSlider (WooThemes).
Plus... I also would like to stop the fade on the background image (after slide 1) if possible.

Here's my [test site](http://dev1.strongtie.com/genuine/template-index2.html).

#### jQuery Code

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    animationLoop: false,
    touch: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 10000,
    startAt: 0,
    pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
    pauseOnHover: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
    start: function(slider){
    jQuery('body').removeClass('loading');

  },

  after: function(slider) {
    jQuery('#backgman').stop("fade");
  },

  end: function(slider){
    // $('#result').load('form.html');
    // window.location = "template-form.html"
    //alert('Ready was performed.');
  }

  }); 

  jQuery('#slide-text').css({zIndex:7}).fadeOut(0);
  jQuery('#slide-text').css({zIndex:6}).fadeOut(0);

});
```

I have an IE8 css file and have used `opacity:inherit; filter:inherit;`
I think I'm really close to getting it... any ideas/suggestions?
Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You must to remove div which you have used in `"UL"` tag and set `float:left` in your `li` style.

It should be like this,

```
<ul>
  <li style="float:left;">...</li>
  <li style="float:left;">...</li>
</ul>
```

For, example, take a look at [this link](http://radiantq.com/) where it was working fine.

Hope, this one will help you!.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up making a conditional for IE8 and used jQuery that removed the fading. I'll give this a shot though.

Comment: I added the floats.. but it's still funky http://dev1.strongtie.com/genuine/template-index2.html